# MockMvc and User Principal

Tags: spring, security, principal, mockmvc

I try to test the access of mvcControllers injecting the UserPrincipal :

**restPockMockMvc
                .perform(get("/pocs").principal(authToken))
                .andReturn();**

and here's the method of the controller I try to test:

**@PreAuthorize(value = "hasRole('AK_ADMIN')")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    public  PagedResources collectionList(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest){
............}**

httpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal()i s always null whereas I inject the userPrincipal and I do not understand why...

Your help would be welcome.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
request.getUserPrincipal();
```